# Appcelerator Alloy project working with Functions or Classes

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I made an **Alloy** project trying to understand how to work with separate JS files.

So far i tried to make *Functions* and *Classes* with no success.

Here's an example of a *Class* that i tried to make.

> index.js

```
var Label = require("test");
label = new Label();

$.index.add(label);
$.index.open();
```

> test.js

```
//Create Function

function Label() {  

// Create label
  var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"qweqwe"
});

// Return label
return label;
}

module.exports = Label;
```

---

*When i try to compile i get this error*

[image]

Can you please demonstrate the proper structure of a *Function* or *Class* that i can later use from an other js file using *module.exports* or *exports*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows that, the file path of test module is wrong.
Add your test.js file in lib folder as shown below, and try

[image]

it works for me. also refer [CommonJs module in Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium)

Comment: True!
My syntax was correct.. all i had to do is just to create a folder named **lib** and put my js inside.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Alloy QuickStart about views, requiring controllers and widgets. what you are doing is mixing classic and alloy with no (clear) reason, which is not considere best practice.